# Styling of lightning-datatable in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, html, lightning-datatable

I am creating a LWC and i was wondering if it is possible to edit the border-color or background-color of the checkbox in a datatable.

[image]

fx if my html datatable looks something like this:

```
<div if:true={MyData}>
        <lightning-datatable data={MyData} 
        columns={columns} 
        key-field="id" max-row-selection="2" 
        onrowselection={rowSelected} 
        selected-rows={preSelectedRows}>
        </lightning-datatable>
```

When i inspect element in a browser, i see the css class names etc as shown below. Is it somehow possible to "override" this with my own values?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It's not possible to style the inner components of a component, as the component itself is exposed to the parent as a single discrete component. You could, for example, add a border to the lightning-datatable itself, but not to anything inside of it.

[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_dom):

> CSS styles defined in a parent component don’t leak into a child. In our example, a p style defined in the todoApp.css style sheet doesn’t style the p element in the c-todo-item component, because the styles don’t reach into the shadow tree. See [CSS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_css_intro).

Comment: Hi sddcfox, thanks for your answer. That is a pity this is not possible. Do you know if this only applies to LWCs? Would it be possible using Aura e.g?

Comment: @AndersenAnd Actually, in LWC, the appropriate solution would be to "extend" the lightning-datatable and use a custom cell type. In Aura, it wouldn't be possible at all.

Comment: @sfdcfox Would that apply towards rounded corners as well? I see that most standard components have the rounded corners. Would that not be possible?

Comment: @bradfordgray As far as I'm aware, that's still the case. You might be interested in looking at npm [lightning-base-components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lightning-base-components) if you want to copy the original components and style them/change their behavior/etc as you desire.

Answer (score 2):

renderedCallback() {

let style = document.createElement('style');

style.innerText = '.slds-table tr:nth-last-child(-n+1){font-weight: bold;background-color: #ADD8E6;}';

this.template.querySelector('lightning-datatable').appendChild(style);

}

Or
let style = document.createElement('style');

style.innerText = '.slds-table{background-color: #f10000; color: #ffff11;}';

this.template.querySelector('lightning-datatable').appendChild(style);

https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/data-tables/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible by creating an external stylesheet i.e for eg:lwcCustomStyle.css(in this you can overwrite the css as per your needs) and storing the same in the static resource named lwcCustomStyle and then include the static resource in your LWC component.js as mentioned below.

```
import lwcCustomStyle from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/lwcCustomStyle';
import { loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader'; 
export default class CommunityTable extends LightningElement {
       renderedCallback() {
        Promise.all([
            loadStyle(this, lwcCustomStyle)
        ])
            .then(() => {
                console.log("All CSS are loaded. perform any initialization function.")
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log("failed to load the css");
            });
    }
  }
```

Comment: You're strongly discouraged from doing this (at least, in Salesforce), because you will also affect parts of the UI you should not be affecting. In addition, this isn't supposed to work with a true native shadow DOM, so some care should be taken if you use this.